# Cakephp2 Router File redirect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I want to redirect a file url of an old website www.test.de/pdf/doc.pdf to the new cake page where the pdf will be in app/webroot/files/doc.pdf. Is this possible with Cakephp? I don't have the option to do rewriting on the webspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Router to redirect:-

```
Router::redirect('/pdf/doc.pdf', '/files/doc.pdf');
```

You'll find further details about redirecting with the Router in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing).

Comment: It's not working. I have to enter index.php/pdf/doc.pdf to trigger this route. Based on that fact the route which is redirected starts with index.php as well. Any other idea?

Comment: @SvenMäurer sorry, it sounds like your issue is that if you go to www.test.de/pdf/doc.pdf you're not even hitting CakePHP which makes sense if you can't rewrite URLs. In which case there is nothing you can do from CakePHP to fix this as your code will never get run. If you can't configure your server to rewrite the URLs I'm not really sure what you can do to fix this. Perhaps re-tag your question to relate to your server setup rather than CakePHP as this isn't really a Cake question.

Comment: I am unfortunately limited by the webspace based on my customer. But anyway thanks for your help!